# Matrix multiplication program crashes at runtime

Tags: c, debugging

I receive no error during compilation, however, when I execute it, the program crashes. I have deduced the error is the line with  `*mat3[x][y]=mat1[x][y]+mat2[x][y]`. What is happening here, and how can I fix it?

```
typedef float matrice[255][255];

void Caricamento(matrice *, int , int , int );
void Molt(matrice *, int , int ); //Prototipi
void Somma(matrice , matrice , matrice *, int , int );
void Stampa(matrice , int , int );

int main()
{
    matrice A, B, C;
    int r, c;
    printf ("Inserisci la dimensione delle matrici A e B per il calcolo 2*A+B:\n");
    scanf ("%d", &r);
    scanf ("%d", &c);
    Caricamento(&A, r, c, 1);
    Caricamento(&A, r, c, 2);
    Molt(&A, r, c);
    Somma(A, B, &C, r, c);
    Stampa(C, r, c);
    return 0;
}

void Molt(matrice *mat1, int x, int y) //Procedura moltiplicazione
{
    int xi=0, yi=0; //Indici
    while(xi<x)
    {
        yi=0; //Reset indice
        while (yi<y)
        {
            *mat1[x][y]*=2; //Moltiplicazione
            yi++;
        }
        xi++;
    }
}

void Somma(matrice mat1, matrice mat2, matrice *mat3, int x, int y) //Procedura somma
{
    int xi=0, yi=0; //Indici
    while(xi<x)
    {
        yi=0; //Reset indice
        while (yi<y)
        {
            *mat3[x][y]=mat1[x][y]+mat2[x][y]; //Somma
            yi++;
        }
        xi++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you're learning C one of the first things to learn is to not abuse global variables like this. Learn about scope and passing things in as needed.

Comment: what is the input? are `r` and `c` larger than 255?

Comment: to start, the program is missing the statement: `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: `[]` Operator has higher precedence than `*`.  use parenthesis, `(*mat)[10][8]` is better than how you have written.

Comment: compiles != correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a matter of [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). The expression `*mat1[x][y]*=2` is parsed as `*(mat1[x][y])*=2`.

Use `(*mat1)[x][y]*=2` instead.

Or rely on the fact that arrays naturally decays to pointers to their first element, and are passed as pointers anyway. So e.g.

```
void Molt(matrice mat1, int x, int y) //Procedura moltiplicazione
{
    ...
    mat1[x][y]*=2;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be

```
(*mat1)[x][y]*=2;
```

Same goes for `mat3` in other function also. Because array subscript has higher precedence than `*` dereference.

Here `matrice*` is of type `float (*)[][]` so you need to get the 2d array by dereferrencing it first.